# Exception after closing the program

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have to debug a program that is going in error when I close it.
I have the "[program name] has stopped working" error.
The instance of Visual Studio with which I run the debug doesn't catch the exception. So, I tried the "debug" button on the error message and I have this error message :
[image: Error message]

This software was working fine on Windows 7 and this happens on Windows 10.

Do you have any idea on what I can do/try ?

Comment: So you have a thread that didnt get terminated, or tried to write after the core part of the app had closed, like forms etc

Comment: I have thought this but  why on Windows 7 it's working and not on 10 if there is a thread issue ?

Comment: Try to disable all resident programs in Windows 10. Maybe  some injected dll fails to deinitialize itself.

Comment: It can also just be a matter of timing differences between the two OSs

Comment: I only have two threads before to quit (one is the main thread and the other is "Worker thread" with no name)

Comment: Youv'e had a look in the event viewer logs right? Might be more details there.

Comment: Yes, there is no usefull information ... and in the call stack, the last call is the display of the main window ... (when I close the program just after starting it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I have found the error and how to solve it.

The application was using MessageBoxHook DLL, when I have stopped to use it, all was working fine.

So, problem solved ! Thanks to everyone !